# AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via UserBillingHistory instances

Tags: python, django

This is my signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    """Receiver to create authoriasation tokens for users"""

    if kwargs.get('raw'):
        return  # ignore for loading fixtures
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
        UserBillingHistory.objects.create(user=instance)

        if settings.NEW_USER_EMAIL is not None:
            send_email(
                "Spotless data - new user",
                "New user with email %s has signed up" % instance.email,
                "Spotless Data<team@spotlessdata.com>",
                settings.NEW_USER_EMAIL
                )
```

This is my model:

class UserBillingHistory(models.Model):

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False, default="Free 100Mb on sign-up and Buy $40 and get 100Mb")
cash_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
data = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=False, null=False)
is_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
job = models.ForeignKey("Job", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

@property
def user_can_view(self, user):
    return (self.user == user)

def user_can_edit(self, user):
    return (self.user == user)

def user_can_delete(self, user):
    return (self.user == user)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/userbillinghistorys/%s/" % self.id

def cash_amount(self):
    return "$%s" % 0

def data(self):
    return 100 * 1024 * 1024    

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.description
```

When i try to create new user signup i am getting below error. 
   AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via UserBillingHistory instances

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode - character maps to

And Regarding this model by default will show content to data=100*1024*1024 and cash_amount=0. 
Can you please suggest regarding it thanks.

Comment: Can you add the full error trace? Can you print `instance` just to confirm that you do the user instance there?

Comment: AttributeError at /account/signup/
Manager isn't accessible via UserBillingHistory instances
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/account/signup/
Django Version: 1.9
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
Manager isn't accessible via UserBillingHistory instances
Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py in __get__, line 250

Comment: Thanks but that's no the full trace :)

Comment: Can you also show your singup view. I doubt the error comes from `create_auth_token`....

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError at /account/signup/
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 510: character maps to <undefined>
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/account/signup/
Django Version: 1.9
Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError
Exception Value: 
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 510: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0):

For the error mentioned in your comments, replace:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s" % "Free 100Mb on sign-up and Buy $40 and get 100Mb"
```

with:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u"Free 100Mb on sign-up and Buy $40 and get 100Mb"
```

Comment: By this also getting unicodeencode error. I was debug but the bug is like here. > c:\python34\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py(195)form_valid()
-> self.get_success_url())
(Pdb) n
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position
512: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: i am using python 3 version

Comment: Ahhhh, it's from self.get_success_url(). That makes sense, see my other answer.

Comment: No difference still getting same error charmap unicodeencode error . I have updated above as your comments please review it.